# cmake include header only library

Tags: c++, cmake, spdlog

I want to include [spdlog](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog) into one of my project. It is a header only library. The project that i am building is using cmake. Currently i am using

```
include_directories('src/logger/spdlog/')
```

in cmake and including the library as

```
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>
```

in logs.h inside logger folder. I am getting fatal error no such file or directory. What is the correct way to include the same library in my application.

Comment: Try with " " instead of <> in the #include

Comment: @JoseLinares working with <> now. Was adding inverted commas extra :p

Comment: @xandercage What are _"inverted-commas"_ please? Did you mean replacing `'` with `""` in the `CMakeLists.txt` code?

Comment: Just removing them. They are not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use single quotes `'` but double quotes `"` or just plain strings if they don't contain spaces.

I would advice you to use `find_path` instead of adding includes directly. There you can add `PATH_SUFFIXES`. You get a message during configuration if the header is not found, which makes it easier to spot errors.
Documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/find_path.html

Answer (score 8):

Cmake provides interface library specifically for "header-only library". I would suggest to do the following:

1. Create a file structure like the following

```
third-party\spdlog\include
```

2. Git clone the spdlog repository into the `include` directory with the name `spdlog`
3. Create `third-party\spdlog\CMakeLists.txt` with the following content

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
add_library(${TARGET_LOGGER} INTERFACE)
# add_library(spdlog::spdlog_header_only ALIAS ${TARGET_LOGGER})
target_include_directories(${TARGET_LOGGER} INTERFACE "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include>"
                                                        "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>")
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_LOGGER} INTERFACE Threads::Threads)
```

4. Define TARGET_LOGGER in the CMakeLists.txt of your project. Link this target to your project with `target_link_libraries(${TARGET_PROJECT} LINK_PUBLIC ${TARGET_LOGGER})`. Also don't forget to

```
add_subdirectory(
    third-party\spdlog
  )
```

Then, in your project, you can use `#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"` to include the library

Comment: this is the best answer, and uses modern cmake practices

Answer (score 5):

You are probably off one directory. Try either

```
 include_directories("src/logger")
```

in the `CMakeLists.txt`, or

```
 #include <spdlog.h>
```

in the source code.

Comment: Thanks that was one of them, but the major issue that i forgot was `inverted-commas` while adding path in include_directories working fine now :)